# Python Interpolation with interp1d: both linear and quadratic kinds give same result

Tags: python, interpolation

I have a python code that should demonstrate the difference between linear and quadratic interpolation, given a data.  However, I find that both linear and quadratic yield the same result!  What gives?  What subtlety am I missing?

```
del f1
del f2
n=10;
x = np.linspace(0, 4, n)
y = np.cos(x**2/3+4)+ 0.1 * np.random.randn(n)
f1 = interp1d(x, y, kind = 'linear')
f2 = interp1d(x, y, kind = 'cubic')


n2=n
xnew = np.linspace(0, 4, n)

plt.subplot(1,2,1)
plt.plot(x, y, 'o', xnew, f1(xnew), '-', xnew, f2(xnew), '--')
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.subplot(1,2,2)
plt.semilogy(xnew, np.abs(f1(xnew)-y), '*', xnew, np.abs(f2(xnew)-y), 'o')
plt.xlabel('xnew')
plt.ylabel('Relative error between \n interpolation (f1 or f2) and actual y ')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

The difference between linear and quadratic interpolation is far too small.  Shouldn't it be greater?  See plot below.  I feel like I may be missing something obvious or some subtlety.

[image]

### Code edited per comments received

I changed the code to a simpler function and increase the number of points in `xnew`.  This made barely any difference.  What is my dumb a*s missing?  Is a linear interpolation (irrespective of how many entries in `xnew`) really that good?

```
x = np.linspace(0,8,n)
y = 0.1*x**2;

f1 = interp1d(x, y, kind='linear')
f2 = interp1d(x, y, kind='quadratic')
xnew = np.linspace(np.min(x), np.max(x), num=250)
plt.plot(xnew, 0.1*xnew**2, '+', xnew, f1(xnew), 'r-', xnew, f2(xnew), 'g--')
plt.xlabel('xnew')
plt.ylabel('y, y(linear interp), y(quadratic interp)')
plt.show()

plt.figure(figsize=(10,4))
plt.subplot(1,3,1)
plt.plot(0.1*xnew**2+np.cos(2*xnew)-f1(xnew))
plt.xlabel('xnew')
plt.ylabel('y(linear interpolation)')

plt.subplot(1,3,2)
plt.plot(0.1*xnew**2+np.cos(2*xnew)-f2(xnew))
plt.xlabel('xnew')
plt.ylabel('y(quadratic interpolation)')

plt.subplot(1,3,3)
plt.plot(f1(xnew)-f2(xnew))
plt.xlabel('xnew')
plt.ylabel('difference betw \n linear and quadratic \n interpolation')
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: You are evaluating your interpolated functions at *exactly the same points* where the original function was defined.  There would ideally be no difference at all at those points!  You need to evaluate at many more points to see the effects of interpolation.

Comment: i.e. increase the number of points in xnew.

Comment: @jasonharper I made an edit.  I find no difference in the way things are.  What is my dumb self missing?

Comment: @Mathieu I made an edit.  I find no difference in the way things are.  What is my dumb self missing?

Comment: Is the problem solved?

Comment: @Mathieu I have unfortunately not got around to implementing what you have done.

Comment: Meaning? Simply copy/pasting the code will yield the same result.

Answer (score 0):

I did not have a full look at what you did, but here is a quick example with your initial data:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

n = 10
x = np.linspace(0, 4, n)
y = np.cos(x**2/3+4)+ 0.1 * np.random.randn(n)

f1 = interp1d(x, y, kind = 'linear')
f2 = interp1d(x, y, kind = 'cubic')

xnew = np.linspace(0, 4, 100)

f, ax = plt.subplots(2, 1, sharex=True)
ax[0].plot(x, y, 'o', xnew, f1(xnew), '-')
ax[1].plot(x, y, 'o', xnew, f2(xnew), '-')
```

Output:

[image]

**EDIT**: With quadratic instead of cubic.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

n = 10
x = np.linspace(0, 4, n)
y = np.cos(x**2/3+4)+ 0.1 * np.random.randn(n)

f1 = interp1d(x, y, kind = 'linear')
f2 = interp1d(x, y, kind = 'quadratic')

xnew = np.linspace(0, 4, 100)

f, ax = plt.subplots(2, 1, sharex=True)
ax[0].plot(x, y, 'o', xnew, f1(xnew), '-')
ax[1].plot(x, y, 'o', xnew, f2(xnew), '-')
```

[image]

Both cubic and quadratic gives more 'rounded' edges.